# How to retain Form Values when error comes on Page

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

When i enter anything wrong in the form and click on save button, then all form values gets clears and error shows on page. 
User is model Object and UserVO is form Object.

I want to retain form values.
What is wrong in my below code ?

```
    public ModelAndView save(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response,UserVO userVO) {
        User user = new User();

        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("registration", "user", userVO);
        BindException errors = new BindException(userVO, "userVO");
        userValidator.validate(userVO, errors);
        if (errors.hasErrors()) {
            mav.addAllObjects(errors.getModel());
            return mav;
        }
```

Comment: Could you apply the code of view?

Comment: Don't create your own `BindException` object, add it has a method argument after the `UserVO` method argument. Reuse that and use the model on construction of the `ModelAndView` don't add it afterwards.

Comment: Pls show you tsp/html file.